# How to create RecordN for generated DAO lookup

Tags: java, jooq

I am using jOOQ's [code generator with DAOs](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.9/manual/code-generation/codegen-daos/).

I have a table with a composite primary key like this:

```
CREATE TABLE telefon_client
(
    telefon VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    client VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    data_alta DATE NOT NULL,
    pendent_ajustar TINYINT(1) DEFAULT '1' NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT `PRIMARY` PRIMARY KEY (telefon, data_alta)
);
```

The generated DAO has a method with this interface:

```
public void deleteById(Record2<String, LocalDate>... ids);
```

I want to implement this method:

```
public void delete(String telefon, LocalDate dataAlta) {
    new TelefonClientDao(configuration).deleteById(????);
}
```

What's the recommended way of building an instance of a Record2 with those two values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one option:

```java
DSL.using(configuration)
   .newRecord(TELEFON_CLIENT.TELEFON, TELEFON_CLIENT.DATA_ALTA)
   .values(telefon, dataAlta);
```